# Calculating the work of the following vector field.

Tags: calculus, geometry, vector-analysis

Thanks in advance for reading my question. I am supposed to calculate $$\int_C F(r) \dot{} dr$$
of the following field: $F(x,y,z)=(y^2,z^2,x^2)$, and $C$ is the intersection of the sphere $\gamma_1: x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ with the cylinder $\gamma_2:x^2+y^2=ax$.

But i am having trouble in finding the intersection of $\gamma_1$ with $\gamma_2$. Any tips?

Comment: Can you confirm the equation for $\gamma_2$?  As it's written now it describes a circular cylinder, not a parabolic one.

Comment: You wrote the wrong equation for $\gamma_1$.  Are you sure that's the right equation for $\gamma_2$?

Comment: Yeah, its a circular cylinder. my bad! I will edit it.

Comment: As for the equations, they are as I wrote (thanks for editing the double $y^2$). A sphere of radius a, centered at (0,0,0) and this cylinder. I can take a screenshot (it's in portuguese) of the given question, if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easiest to start by finding a parameterization for the circle $x^2 + y^2 = ax$ in the $xy$-plane.  To do this, note that
$$
x^2 + y^2 = ax \implies x^2 - ax + \frac {a^2}{4} + y^2 = \frac{a^2}{4} \implies\\
(x - a/2)^2 + y^2 = (a/2)^2
$$
We can parametrize this in the usual way one parameterizes a circle:
$$
\tilde{\mathbf r}(t) = \frac a2( \cos(t), \sin(t) ) + (a/2,0) = \left(\frac a2(\cos(t) + 1), \frac a2 \sin(t) \right); \qquad t \in [0,2\pi]
$$
To get the formula for the intersection, note that the sphere can be written as 
$$
z = \pm \sqrt{a^2 - x^2 - y^2}
$$
The intersection of our cylinder with the upper hemisphere can be parameterized as
$$
\mathbf r(t) = (\tilde r_x, \tilde r_y, \sqrt{a^2 - \tilde r_x^2 + \tilde r_y^2}) \\
= \left(\frac a2(\cos(t) + 1), \frac a2 \sin(t), 
\sqrt{a^2 - a^2/2 - (a^2/2)\cos(t)}\right)
\\ 
=
\left(\frac a2(\cos(t) + 1), \frac a2 \sin(t), 
\frac{a}{\sqrt 2}\sqrt{1 - \cos(t)}\right); \qquad t \in [0,2\pi]
$$
We can separately parameterize the intersection with the lower hemisphere as
$$
\left(\frac a2(\cos(t) + 1), \frac a2 \sin(t), 
-\frac{a}{\sqrt 2}\sqrt{1 - \cos(t)}\right); \qquad t \in [0,2\pi]
$$ 
Interestingly, these parameterizations intersect at $t = \pi/2$.

Comment: Notably, it might be easier to calculate this integral using Stokes' theorem.

Comment: I see, thanks for your time, I can't use Stokes' theorem, as II am supposed to calculate this line integral. Also, another small question regarding this topic. Finding the intersection of such surfaces follows some kind of "easier" guideline? I mean, finding the intersection of a cylinder and a sphere is usually easier if one parametrizes first?

Comment: @FightDepressionWithKnowledge Well, I exploited the fact that the cylinder is given by an equation on only $x$ and $y$ in this case.  I don't think this trick generalizes to situations where the surfaces are more complicated.